# a loop in my destructor never ends

Tags: c++, boost, destructor, static-members

this is a piece of code from one of my destructors my application. look at the debug part please

```
BasicLogger::~BasicLogger(){
    if (logFile.is_open()) {
        flushLog();
        logFile.close();
    }
    for (outIt it(out_.begin()); it != out_.end();safe_delete_item(it->second), it++);

    //debug code

    std::cout << "Number of threads used: " << BasicLogger::threads.size() << std::endl;
    for(std::map <boost::thread::id, int>::iterator item = threads.begin(); item != threads.end(); item++)
    {
        std::stringstream out("");
        out << item->first;
        std::cout << "Thread[" << item->first << "] called out " << item->second << "  times" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Number of flushes to files " << BasicLogger::flushCnt  << std::endl;
    //debug...
}
```

and, if it helps, here is some declaration from the hpp file

```
class BasicLogger{
//... 
    //for debugging purpose only
    static std::map <boost::thread::id, int> threads;
    static int flushCnt;
}
```

and their definition in cpp

```
std::map <boost::thread::id, int> BasicLogger::threads= std::map <boost::thread::id, int>();
int BasicLogger::flushCnt = 0;
```

you want to see the out put:

```
Number of threads used: 3
Thread[7f0a0c7e8700] called out 2  times
Thread[7f0a157ea700] called out 42  times
Thread[7f0a2f35a7c0] called out 15940  times
Thread[ffffffff] called out 1630561847  times
```

`size` of the container shows 3 while it prints 4 and that is it, the loop is never ending, and the application shows cpu usage of %100+

- I dont think anybody else is filling up `threads` . This happens at the end of my application.
- in addition to  `ffffffff`, I have seen `{Not-any-thread}` also!!!
- yes, I am iterating through a static member from within a destructor(for debug purpose only). it looks weird, but I am not sure if it is the source of my problem. what do you think?

can you help me find out why I am getting this and how to avoid it?

Comment: Try to fully qualify `threads` within the loop (`BasicLogger::threads` not `threads`). Does that help? I guess, that the condition `it != threads.end()` will never be false.

Comment: Is there any chance that `threads` is modified by a different thread during the loop?

Comment: @molbdnilo no it is not .

Comment: @StefanWeiser no it didnt help

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything *wrong* with the code but have some suggestions which *may* help:

- use a `const_iterator` to iterate, as you are not modifying anything in the map.
- store `threads.end()` before looping
- use the pre-increment form of ++ (so `++item` rather than `item++`), which is slightly more efficient as you're not using the value of this operation.

The for loop would therefore end up something like:

```
for(std::map <boost::thread::id, int>::const_iterator item = threads.begin(), end_item = threads.end(); item != end_item; ++item)
{
    ...
}
```

Otherwise, as others have said, I can only assume that something on another thread is consuming an entry in the map, causing your iterator to simply miss the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug somewhere else in your code.

Do you use the `[]` operator on your `threads` map anywhere in your code ? It may created an entry with wrong values in your map. Try to replace with calls to `at()` unless you explicitly want the insertion side-effect of `[]`.

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Another possibility is that you instantiate two `BasicLogger` in your program. As `threads` is  static both `BasicLogger` will share the same `theads` variables.

Yet another possibility is that you try to update the `threads` map in two different threads (as your program look multi-threaded). `std::map` is not thread-safe and must be protected by a mutex.

You could also move your debug code to the very top of your destructor to see if this thread id is not changed by the destructor code.